# Firebase Realtime Database query for specific string on android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to make a query where I can search for a specific String so it can display all the data associated with that string and similars.

What I've managed so far is: `Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("name").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");` s here is the user input on an EditText field, sent from here this listener:

```
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                search(s.toString());
            }
            else search("");

        }
    });
```

And what this does is simply display all the results similar to the string written:

Example: I query for "Te" and I have 3 fields which are named the following: **"Test" "Test Edited" "Edited Test"** The query will then display me **"Test"** and **"Test Edited"** but not "Edited Test" If i search for **"Edited"** I get **"Edited Test"** but not the other one also named **"Edited".**

Is there a way to make it search for the value on the entire string? Also is there a way to make it so that capslocked words do not matter to the query? Say I have **"Test"** and **"test"** and i search for **"t"** can i make it so that it displays both instead of just **"test"**?

Comment: Realtime Database does not have queries for substrings.  You can query for strings that begin with some value, but that's it.

Comment: Ah Bummer. Elasticsearch's the only option then?

Comment: There are a lot of search engines out there.

Comment: Can you specify some?

Comment: Recommendations for software is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Web searches will give you plenty of options.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway!